# Sum 2 arrays with differents keys

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, php-5.3

I have a problem with my sum of arrays. So I have this array :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [totalGames] => 21
        [nature] => 542
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [totalGames] => 2
        [nature] => 418
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [totalGames] => 26
        [nature] => 728
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [totalGames] => 3
        [nature] => 542
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [totalGames] => 2
        [nature] => 418
    )

)
```

I want to make a sum of this array to get this result :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [totalGames] => 24
        [nature] => 542
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [totalGames] => 4
        [nature] => 418
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [totalGames] => 26
        [nature] => 728
   )
)
```

I tried like this :

```
while ($aRecord = $rResult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        if($aData['nature'] == $aRecord['nature']){
            $aData[] = $aRecord;
        }else{
            $aData['nature']      =   $aRecord['nature'];
            $aData['totalGames']  +=  $aRecord['nature']['totalGames'];
        }
    }
```

But not work. What I'm doing wrong ? Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english.

---

I also tried but it did not work :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalGames, nature FROM master WHERE date(date)="2015-11-20" GROUP BY nature ORDER by totalGames
```

Comment: you can get this result from database direct using group by nature,sum of totalGames

Comment: I tried but no work : `SELECT COUNT(*) as totalGames, nature FROM `master` WHERE date(date)="2015-11-20"  GROUP BY nature ORDER by totalGames
`

Comment: check my ans you can get right result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
$myArr = array(array('totalGames' => 21, 'nature' => 542),array('totalGames' => 2,'nature' => 418),array('totalGames' => 26,'nature' => 728), array('totalGames' => 3,'nature' => 542),array('totalGames' => 2,'nature' => 418));
$sum = array_reduce($myArr, function ($a, $b) {
    isset($a[$b['nature']]) ? $a[$b['nature']]['totalGames'] += $b['totalGames'] : $a[$b['nature']] = $b;  
    return $a;
});
print_r($sum);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try as

```
while ($aRecord = $rResult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $hash = $aRecord['nature'];
    if(isset($aData[$hash])){
        $aData[$hash]['totalGames']  +=  $aRecord['totalGames'];
    }else{
        $aData[$hash]['nature']     =   $aRecord['nature'];
        $aData[$hash]['totalGames']  =   $aRecord['totalGames'];
    }
}
```